# RegEx para la contraseña en js

Tags: javascript, regex

El tema es que no lo comprueba bien, lo he probado de muchas maneras pero no funciona.
Quiero que cuando no cumpla ese formato entre en esa condi, pero nunca entra aun incumpliendolo

```
//regexp password

....
    var strongRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})");

    else if(strongRegex.match(this.form.password) == false){
              this.error.show = true;
              this.error.message = 'La contraseña no cumple los requisitos';
            }

....
```

Answer (score 2):

No pones un ejemplo de entrada en tu post, sería bueno que la incluyeras. A mi entender serviría usar la función **test**, en vez de **match**. La función **test** te devolverá un booleano, la función **match** un arreglo.

```
let arr = "Java es mejor que Javascript".match(/Java/gi);
```

Esto me devolverá un arreglo, porque la cadena cumple con el patrón a buscar(Java).

```
let nombreConJ = /^J|j/;
let resultado = nombreConJ.test("Juan Jacobo Rosseau");
```

Esto dará como resultado un true, ya que cumple con el patrón de que la cadena empiece con una letra j en mayúscula o minúscula. en tu código creo que usar test convendría mejor que usar match.

```
var strongRegex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})/;

 /*
  Si test da false es que la entrada no cumple con el patrón definido
 */
    if(!strongRegex.test(this.form.password)){
        this.error.show = true;
        this.error.message = 'La contraseña no cumple los requisitos';
        alert('La contraseña no cumple los requisitos')
    }
```

Una entrada como ésta `gene$R4l09544` es válida.
Una entrada como ésta `1233` no sería válida. Espero haber ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

## El error

El error aquí es que `match` **no devuelve** ni `true` ni `false`. `match` devuelve `null` en caso de no hallar coincidencias (aunque la verdad me gustaría que devolviese un `array` vacío). En caso de hallar coincidencias, **devuelve un `array` con todas las coincidencias**.

**El único que te puede ayudar es `test`**.

### Uso de `test`

`test` devuelve `true` o `false` dependiendo de si halla o no una coincidencia. A quien verdaderamente necesitas es a `test` porque **estás intentando evaluar si encaja o no con `match`**, que devuelve `null` o un array con las coincidencias.

#### Sintaxis

La sintaxis de `test` es la siguiente:

```
miExpresionRegular.test(cadena)
```

Donde:

- **miExpresionRegular** es una expresión regular.
- **cadena** es a quien le vas a hacer tu prueba de coincidencia.

### Solución

Cambia la forma en la que compruebas la existencia/coincidencia de dicha cadena con tu expresión regular:

```
//regexp password

....
    var strongRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})");

    if (strongRegex.test(this.form.password) === false)
        this.error.show = true;
        this.error.message = 'La contraseña no cumple los requisitos';
    }
....
```

**Espero que haya sido de utilidad.**

Comment: Si, así si que se puede crear una expresión regular: `new RegExp("cadena")`. Por favor, corrige esa parte de tu respuesta porque es errónea y puede confundir a otros usuarios que busquen soluciones parecidas. Más información en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). Saludos

Comment: Ya cambié la respuesta.